# Facebook SDK : URL of the RSS feed for facebook notifications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

Is there a way of obtaining the RSS feed url for facebook notifications via Facebook SDK?
I'm using the PHP version.

Thank You

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to achieve this via Facebook functionality.

Comment: @Tobi : Is there a way of generating it? It contains a id attribute which is the facebook id and a key attribute. I don't know what that key is. 
E.g : 
id = 100001444273394
key = AWiVVNlBfK8I9PcN in the following feed URL

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=100001444273394&viewer=100001444273394&key=AWiVVNlBfK8I9PcN&format=rss20

Comment: You could just parse the RSS with PHP, no need for the Facebook PHP SDK: http://rssphp.net/

Comment: I want to get the RSS url via the SDK, just like you could get user name or email via the SDK.

Comment: OK. Like I wrote, I'm not aware that this is possible.